# best tools for theme design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i am looking for bests and usable tools for creating wordpress themes..
and i Astounding in this process
i want something like jQuery to do many things easily like fade, slide, selecting  ... effects. id don't like to use frameworks that help to create faster like bootstrap or etc just want something that has powerful tools for theme design.
like jquery or less....
i find many tools and i don't know exact usage of them
react.js, mootools, ember.js, backbone.js, angular and ....
what usage of them? 
is jquery UI useful?
thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Angular JS, emberJS, Backbone JS are all MVC JS frameworks.
These are strong and powerful with data binding techniques, data manipulation and service integration, UI designing proficiency and maintaining dependency if any.

Like for Eg. AngularJS is a JavaScript framework. It can be added to an HTML page with a '<'script> tag.
AngularJS extends HTML attributes with Directives, and binds data to HTML with Expressions.

So, in your case what you need is to design UI but not manipulate data or bind data so you can use UI designing tools like HTML 5 and CSS3, SASS/SCSS, Bootstrap etc.
**OR**
you can use some predefined themes which some support or website team has already created it for use but sometimes you need to purchase it, license it and you can directly integrate these themes and start with your coding stuff.
Websites like *WIX.com, INSPINIA* etc have predefined themes which we can use.

Please mark this solution and vote if it's useful.

**Thanks!**